# How to do a moving MAX based on some rule in a data frame?

Tags: r

```
> days=Sys.Date()-1:70
> price=abs(rnorm(70))
> regular=rep(c(0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1),c(7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7))
> y=data.frame(cbind(days,price,regular))
```

y is like
      days      price regular
1  14990 0.16149463       0
2  14989 1.69519358       0
3  14988 1.57821998       0
4  14987 0.47614311       0
5  14986 0.87016180       0
6  14985 2.55679229       0
7  14984 0.89753533       0

the output I want:
have another column appended to y, whose value is the max price in the recent 2 **regular** weeks.
So if the current row is today, then get the max price of the past 14 days (including today) if the last 2 week
are regular weeks,  if one of the last 2 weeks is not regular week, then I need to go back further to find the max
price, as I need the max price for the last 2 **regular** weeks. How can I do that? Or I have to use loop/if to do it?

BTW, why the days is like 14990,14989, after cbind(days,price,regular)? before the cbind, days is like
the format "2010-12-23".

Comment: `days` is converted to numeric because none of the arguments to `cbind` are a `data.frame`, so `cbind` returns a matrix.  `data.frame(cbind(...))` is redundant anyway.

Comment: Do you know what makes a week regular? This could allow for a much easier and more eloquent solution. Also, you can wrap you data frame creation into one line: `y <- data.frame(days = Sys.Date() - 1:70, price = abs(rnorm(70)), regular = rep(c(0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1), c(7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7)))`, which avoids the date problem. The easiest solution likely uses an `xts` or `zoo` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that a day is regular if regular == 1, for each row i we consider the rows 1 to i, remove the non-regular rows and return NA if there are no rows left or return the largest of the last 14 otherwise.

```
y <- data.frame(days, price, regular)
y$max <- sapply(1:nrow(y), function(i) with(subset(y[1:i, ], regular == 1), 
        if (length(regular) == 0) NA else max(tail(price, 14))))
```

Comment: Thank, what's the meaning of y[1:3,,drop = FALSE]? What does the drop mean here?

Comment: You are right. Its not really needed (although it does not hurt). If y had only one column then y[1:i,] would reduce to a vector (rather than a data frame) if drop=FALSE were not specified. Here y has more than one column so we don't really need it but I tend to add this by habit since omitting it is often the source of programming errors in R.  I will remove it.